# Do comment flags deemed helpful apply to badge requirements?

Tags: support, badges, flags, helpful-flags

Do comment flags deemed helpful count toward the Deputy and Marshall badge requirements, or is it only question and answer flags that count?

Comment: Yes they are; Proof is given in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/150074/152859)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only the flags for moderator attention are counted for getting the Deputy, and Marshall badges; this, for example, excludes the flags for spam posts.

On a site, I didn't get the Marshall badge, even if my total helpful flags are more than 500; that is because my flags for moderator attention are just 387.

**Update**: Moderators don't get those badges, and the site I was referring to is the site where I am a moderator. It is not true that only flags for moderator attention are considered for getting those badges.

Comment: I'd really like a dev to confirm this, as comment flags weren't tracked previously and wouldn't have counted.

Comment: @kiamlaluno if you can get confirmation i'll mark this as an answer. I'm looking for something "official". Thanks.

Comment: Wrong. See [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/150074/152859). :-)

Answer (score 10):

Yes they do. While can't find any official documentation for this, I can prove it with the help of Yannis who was kind enough to give screenshot of his flag history at http://workplace.stackexchange.com: ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/150074/152859))

> [image]

And as you can see here, the badge is all his:

> [image]