# What is the deputy badge awarded for?

Tags: discussion, support, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

I want to know what "Raised 80 helpful flags" means. Should I flag 80 comments, or what?

Comment: No, not comments - only flagged posts are counted as far as I know.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No,comments are also counted

Comment: Have a look at [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/187824)

Comment: @BhuvanRikka can you find proof for that?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Comment flags count (unfortunately).

Comment: Hey guys who down-voted my question and did not leave a comment?

Comment: @YannisRizos can you point on something to confirm this?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd yup..check my answer

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yes, my flagging history ;P

Comment: @BhuvanRikka sorry but your answer is not a proof.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd check it now

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd If you have flagged any comment is and it deemed helpful then look at your flag summary and count it with total count. Total count also include helpful flagged comment.

Comment: @Yannis still not sure. Maybe only "moderator attention flags" are counted?

Comment: @BhuvanRikka it's only proof that comment flags are **counted**; it's not a proof they affect that deputy badge.

Comment: @hims056 *Total count also include helpful flagged comments* - says who? Can you find official source?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd ok count all the helpful flags in the image,and i'll post one more pic which show's that comment flag is counted

Comment: @BhuvanRikka you miss my point. See my reply comment to hims056.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Check my answer, added a screenshot of my flagging history in the one site that I have less than 80 post flags _and_ the deputy badge.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd check the total count in the newly added pic.. It includes the comment flag.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd [Proof](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/187824) `Comment flags do not affect the user in any way if a comment gets deleted, but they do count towards your helpful flags.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that at least 80 flags you raised were deemed helpful by the moderator(s) that handled them. There are some instances where a flag is automatically deemed helpful, for example if you flag a question as Off Topic and then a 3K+ user votes to close it as such.

Since you brought this up in the context of the deputy badge, you should keep in mind that flags are (mostly) handled by moderators, and if you go around mindlessly flagging just to get a badge, you may get in trouble.

As for the side question on whether comment flags count towards the deputy badge, well here's my flagging history on The Workplace:

[image]

Obviously I couldn't have gotten the badge if comment flags didn't count, but [here it is](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/badges/70/deputy). ;)

Comment: Also worth to mention that wrong flagging (meaning flag will be declined) will decrease the amount of flags you can use per day.

Comment: Thanks guys, just wanted to know what is it.

Comment: Thanks, your answer also solve [this issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123335/do-comment-flags-deemed-helpful-apply-to-badge-requirements)!

Comment: Please tell me where I can see this information (like on your screen shot) ?

Comment: @Stas open your profile page and click on the helpful flags link

Comment: @Stas http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/782334

Comment: @Stas If you have at least one helpful flag, it will show in your profile. If it does, just click the link...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Ah, I think comment flags started counting at a later time than kiamlaluno's answer.

Comment: Oh my. can you track this down somehow?

Comment: ah thanks..I have one on stackoverflow

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No need, just post an updated answer to that question, feel free to use my screenshot here. kiamlaluno is on a vacation right now, but I'm sure he'll notice your comment there and either remove or update his answer when he's back.

Comment: [Done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/150079/152859) - thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: Did you get the badge before the rule change?

Comment: @ChrisF I don't think Workplace existed before the rule change.

Comment: Oh. I couldn't tell from the screenshot and didn't bother to check the link :)

Answer (score 1):

Flags aren't meant only for comments. You can flag questions,answers,users(who does nasty things like voting fraud) and also comments. Those flags are only counted when they are *helpful*. A moderator should approve that those flags helped in some way!

[image: img]

Comment: There's a small mistake in your answer, you _can't_ flag users. And how would you know if users are engaging in voting fraud in the first place?

Comment: @YannisRizos Not exactly flagging user. I mean flagging their posts for a moderator attention. I flagged two users whose reputation smelled fishy and i got them as helpful! You can't exactly tell whether they've used sock-puppet or not. But, checking the rep history can give you enough instinct if all their answers were upvoted in a short span of time ;)

Comment: Please keep in mind that helpful doesn't necessarily mean correct, your flags being deemed helpful may just mean that the moderators are acknowledging that something smelled fishy, but it could have been nothing in the end.

Comment: @YannisRizos Ya i can understand. I didn't blame anyone for doing so. I just expressed my doubt and asked the mods to check for it. And i was right. One got banned for a month and the other's reputation was reversed the next day!

Comment: Oh, I wasn't saying you blamed anyone, just that "helpful" isn't confirmation that you were correct in thinking that voting fraud is going on. But, of course, seeing the one user suspended _is_ confirmation that your flag was correct.