# I got the Marshal badge with less than 500 helpful flags

Tags: bug, badges, meta, flags

I got the [Marshal badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/160/marshal?userid=140449), but my helpful flags on this site are actually less that the half.

> [image: screeshot]

I have more than 500 helpful flags on Stack Overflow, but I got the badge there much earlier than 7 hours ago.

These are the helpful flags I have.

- Moderator attention flags: 204
- Posts marked spam:           10
- Posts marked offensive:       5
- Comments flagged:            25

The total is exactly 244. Even if the comment flags would count toward the number of helpful flags, they would not make the helpful flags more than 500.

#### Update

Today, the helpful flags are reported to be 600. Differently from yesterday, the helpful moderator attention flags are now 563. The number of helpful flags doesn't match the total reported in my profile page (563 + 10 + 5 + 25 = 603). Since some days ago, the flag summary reports also how the comment flags were handled, but I don't see other type of flags being shown in the summary. (I read "not constructive / off-topic" or "obsolete" in the summary.)

Comment: Does it count comment flags as well?  Do you by chance have 256 helpful comment flags?

Comment: @Servy No, I don't have that much comment flags marked as helpful. As I can see in other sites, like Stack Overflow, I gain the badge when the helpful flag count I see in my profile shows 500 or more.

Comment: @Lix Comment flags count towards the badge: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/150074/168333

Comment: I can't find the post, but I think I remember there being a brief bug where all close votes were counted as helpful flags. (Probably related to how they seem to be in the process of moving to the flag summary page from the votes page.) Perhaps Marshal badges were inappropriately awarded while this was the case, and were not revoked.

Comment: @JeremyBanks http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184338/close-votes-are-counting-as-flags