# Rankings regarding "helpful flags", "edited", "vote count"?

Tags: discussion, reputation, flags

The "gamification" is mainly built around *reputation*, so it is straight forward to get a ranking of community members by reputation points (example: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all)).

I did a bit of searching, but I found no simple way to create such rankings for other numbers, such as "helpful flags", "posts edited", or "vote count". So: how to get to such rankings?

(I am almost certain that my question must be a duplicate, but again: I couldn't identify one.)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters and https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors are relevant. Also, there used to be something called 'flag weight', but I don't think there was a ranking page for that. Basic flag data (number of helpful flags) is probably available through SEDE though.

Comment: Except "helpful flag" I think the rest is available on Users page on the left navigation bar, check the other filters such as "voters" and "editors" (on mobile, sorry for terse comment)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ranking by votes and edits are already there, one click away: (Voters and Editors tabs)

> [image]

e.g. All Time top voter of Stack Overflow is [gnat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839601/gnat) with no less than 104,149 votes cast. (!)

As for helpful flags ranking, it is already asked for in [Is there any place to see a leaderboard of top "Helpful Flaggers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308760/is-there-any-place-to-see-a-leaderboard-of-top-helpful-flaggers).

Answer (score 5):

For helpful flags, you can check which users have the [Marshal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/160/marshal) badge; if there are not too many, you can examine their profiles and fetch the actual number of helpful flags. I know someone who did this for Ask Ubuntu, and without realizing I wrote this very answer I have written a script for this as well which I shared [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332733/295232).

Up- & downvotes are rather easy, they are stored on the user record in SEDE. Example query [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/920649). Total votes is even easier, see @ShadowWizard's answer.