# Is "helpful flag" data accessible via SEDE?

Tags: discussion, flags, data-explorer

I'm looking to find the top flaggers on a given site, and am trying to do so in SEDE.

I was inclined to write up a SEDE query, but, to my amateur eye, there doesn't seem  to be [any table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede/2678#2678) that lists helpful flags. Nor are there any [pre-written queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/rpg/queries?order_by=popular&q=flags) that seem to do this already.

Also, on the post [Is there any place to see a leaderboard of top "Helpful Flaggers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308760/is-there-any-place-to-see-a-leaderboard-of-top-helpful-flaggers) no SEDE options are given.

Is this data just not available on SEDE? Or am I missing it?

If not, and simply out of curiosity as I learn more about SEDE, is there a specific reason why this field is not captured in SEDE?

Comment: @Glorfindel I'm not sure if that edit helped, but I pivoted it to maybe make it not a duplicate. I'm curious about the SEDE part specifically now (even though the other answers gave me an alternate way).

Comment: I'm sure it's not available in SEDE. I'm sure @rene would've written such a query by now.

Comment: @Glorfindel that definitely sounds like a reasonable conclusion. Does it strike you as weird that this field in particular is omitted? I'm really new to SEDE, but it seems like most other data is captured in it.

Comment: Perhaps the field was introduced later than SEDE itself, and it has never been ported?

Comment: @Glorfindel Do you think that might be worthwhile enough to open the question to get an answer to?

Comment: Hmmm ... the duplicates don't answer *why* the field was left out, but on the other hand you might never get a satisfactory answer to that question.

Comment: @Glorfindel technically, neither of the links answer the question of availability either (I did already look at and link to the database schema). Then again, I was assuming that I was missing or misunderstanding something. Either way, it's not a huge deal.

Comment: Probably some useful information here: "[Should the number of helpful flags be public to anyone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249981/282094)".

Comment: A lot of stuff that surrounds moderating actions from users is either not in the public SEDE instance and if it is, it is anonymised / lacking a userid field. Helpful flags sits probably in the same bag as the people reached statistic: not in the user table, so it will not become available in the Public schema.