# Implement flagger ranking

Tags: feature-request, flags

We have a ranking for most votes cast, for most posts edited, but there is no ranking for most flags. Can we add another tab to https://stackoverflow.com/users that will show the most avid flaggers?

I would like to see the new tab added here:

[image]

I know a [question similar to this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308760/is-there-any-place-to-see-a-leaderboard-of-top-helpful-flaggers) was asked before, but the solutions there are not very performant and not in real-time.

Comment: I'm not sure that a ranking system for flags would be *that* helpful. I think I agree with [Tinkeringbell ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/369802/tinkeringbell)'s opinion about the list of top voters or top editors. I even say that as somebody who would be in 3rd place on Stack Overflow ([me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1364007/wai-ha-lee?tab=topactivity)) (116k) (behind [Andy ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189134/andy?tab=topactivity) (130k) and [Floern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559745/floern?tab=topactivity) (235k).

Comment: (assuming that nobody has raised 95k new helpful flags since 2019-08-27 when the list in the linked question was updated to show all 20k+ helpful flag users).

Comment: @WaiHaLee I have generated a list today with relative changes. https://gist.github.com/kamil-tekiela/37ef186b9ab58dc86fe3091882c3673b

Comment: I have implemented such ranking and I host it here http://flaggers.dharman.net/ but it's rarely updated.

Answer (score 12):

> Can we add another tab to https://stackoverflow.com/users that will show the most avid flaggers?

I'm not a fan of this, but to be fair I'm also not a fan of having the 'voters' or 'editors' there: Quantity doesn't mean quality, and I'd rather see leaderboards focus on 'rewarding' quality over quantity. As such, I'm going to have to assume that with 'most avid flaggers' you mean those users with the most *helpful* flags, just to be a bit more charitable towards this request, and implementing at least a semblance of a focus on quality over quantity.

Even then, huge quantities of comment flags on decades old posts with only 50% marked helpful can get you on a leaderboard like this, while someone that flags a lot less but more quality stuff (recent posts, suspected sock rings) might never get there. So, such a leaderboard would not put a spotlight on quality flaggers, it would highlight quantity flaggers.

Also, more gamification of flagging by adding a leaderboard like this might cause more problems than it's worth. As a moderator it's not uncommon to see someone almost mechanically flagging certain posts/comments because they want the [Marshal badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/160/marshal). These flags aren't technically wrong, but they're often 'incomplete', the most common example is flagging single comments as no longer needed based on keywords, while more comments in the thread would need to go as well, like orphaned replies. Usually, this behavior now stops once the badge is earned. Adding a leaderboard would push this one step further: now people have to keep raising these flags to earn/keep their top spot on the leaderboard.

I would much rather see the whole idea of having leaderboards revisited to better highlight quality of contributions instead of quantity, over adding another tab that has the same flaws as existing ones.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. Gamification is good as long as it provides good results. As you said people flag comments to get a badge, but without the badge a lot of comments would never get flagged. While I agree that it adds work for moderators, the idea of getting more flags is good on its own. Of course I meant only helpful flags. We should not count rejected or withdrawn flags.

Comment: Only 675 flags? Please work on your flag ranking!

Comment: @Dharman "Gamification is good as long as it provides good results" < The idea that more flags (just quantity, not looking at whether they're helpful/quality) as a result of gamification is by definition a 'good result' is where we disagree. Just listing 'helpful' flags in such a leaderboard still doesn't say anything about quality overall: This person could've been flagging 200 decade-old low-impact things, have 100 flags marked helpful, and outrank the next person that flagged 100 recent higher impact things and had 90 marked helpful.

Comment: What does the age have to do with it? I'd say that 10 helpful flags on old content is better than 100 helpful flags on new content. Or at least they should be treated as equal

Comment: @Dharman don't worry, moderators *do* have to treat all flags equal. 'Age' is relevant in that there are only a few decade-old posts that still get 100s of visitors each day, most very old posts don't get many views. So (robo)flagging a comment containing e.g. 'thanks' on a decade-old post has a much lower useful impact than flagging a rude comment on a post that's currently on the front page. If moderators are drowned out with flags for minor things on age-old posts, we might miss the stuff that new visitors to our sites actually are confronted with!

Comment: Ah, so the distinction is not the age, but the weight of the flag. Rude flags are more useful than NLN.

Comment: @Dharman and a rude flag on something on the front page that's getting 10s of views each hour is more impactful than a rude flag on something that's a decade old and only gets 2 views a year. Yes, basically.

Comment: I would also argue that most of the site's traffic goes to old questions. I have no data for this, but that was the goal of Stack Overflow. So attending to these questions is really important. I spend a lot of time reading old posts, and I flag stuff whenever I can. The reason to robo-flag NLN comments is because of the rate limit. It would take too long to manually flag them. Most robo-flags are handled by the system. True, that comment flags are easy to cast, but a lot of flags are cast on posts. All flags are valuable

Comment: @Dharman we're just going in circles now: I'm saying that as a moderator, some flags to me achieve more than others, and that a leaderboard will most likely encourage more of those 'little value' flags that achieve next to nothing, besides being technically correct, and that I don't necessarily need more of those flags to handle. You keep insisting each flag has value, and should be treated the same, and that gamification could encourage more flags. At this point, you have your question and I have my answer... I don't think either is going to convince the other that theirs is correct.

Comment: I think the *"quantity vs quality"* argument doesn't apply here very well because you can't find a metric for it except *maybe* counting characters or using some *yet to be invent* AI. Besides for edits below 2k the reviewers in the queue are more demanding than one might think.

Answer (score 3):

I think this can be a good idea, but it would definitely need to have some restrictions.

For starters, *No Longer Needed comment flags would not count towards the ranking*. The other comment flags are more helpful (such as the rude flags, or the custom flag), but NLN doesn't have as much impact as the other flags, as other people have stated.

Aditionally, if any user goes below a certain percentage of helpful flags (say 70 percent helpful flags) **for that specific time period** (for instance, say month or year), they are not eligible to be on the rankings. This ensures that those who try to game the system, or those who don't know how to properly flag won't be on the rankings.

I feel that these restrictions would ensure that those who mechanically flag just to get helpful flags wouldn't be on the rankings anymore, as some people speculated would be a problem with introducing this feature.

---

Another point raised by [bad_coder](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366992/500111) was that the users who have bots doing a lot of flagging are sure to dominate the leaderboard. I don't think this is a problem, because if someone can create a bot to accurately flag and clean the site up, then that bot can certainly be up there. It's a smart bot, it *deserves* the ranking :)

Comment: It's worth noting that it's not uncommon for people (including me) to flag comments that are no longer needed with a custom comment flag explaining _why_ they're no longer needed, for cases where it's not immediately obvious.  I'm thus unsure that not counting NLN flags would be as helpful as would be desired, since anyone trying to game the flag could simply do this instead.

Comment: @RyanM But you don't game the system (AFAIK, ofc ;). Most people who want to be on the rankings would NLN away. If they had to do something which required more effort to be on the leaderboard, well then mission accomplished, right? They aren't doing the low effort method anymore.

Comment: Saying NLN flags don't have an impact is just a local meta myth. Besides folks watching channels like Charcoal would get all the flags while folks methodically cleaning up comment sections wouldn't see their work count towards the ranking. This post is based on a wrong premise.

Comment: @bad_coder cleaning up a comment section should not be done with induvidual NLN flags anyways. A mod flag is in order so they get credit.

Comment: @10Rep contrary to what you're saying [it's not mandatory to raise custom mod flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338911) with some mods saying they prefer individual NLN flags being raised. Since last time [the distinction was brought](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401892) I still feel that rational is missing something.

Comment: @bad_coder Unless there's only one comment on the post, you shouldn't really raise an NLN because a lot of the time it will leave the other comments out of context. And anyways, if someone mostly cleaning up comment sections methodically wouldn't raise only NLN's. They would also raise mod flags because they are cleaning fluff up (which means comment threads).

Comment: @10Rep again not true. For example, in most cases you'll have several comments (lets say 10) that are intertwined where 5 should be kept and 5 should go. By flagging individually you're sparing the mod some effort by handing him a cherry-picked selection.

Comment: @bad_coder why should 5 be kept and 5 go? The 5 that stay are probably out of context. And anyways couldn't you say which 5 should go in the mod flag?

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIGoO.png) is an example of a comment chain where some comments should/could be kept and others are obviously chatty and should be removed:  No context is lost by deleting the comments that I've highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

I think the idea is cool but it introduces one bias:

- Users that have bots flagging for them are bound to dominate the ranking.

And that is anti-pattern, because in the other leaderboards you can still see that most edits and rep are gained manually.

Comment: Well... Ok, so there are bots that make automatic edits and flag automatically, but that still counts as my edit and my flag. Just because I figured out a way how to do it faster doesn't mean that I am not responsible for it.

Comment: But are the bots effective flaggers? In other words: do they clean the site from low quality stuff? If yes, what is the problem?

Comment: @rene I'm not necessarily saying that's a problem! I'm bringing up the issue if we want more rankings that will predictably be *"top-heavy"* with bot users. (If that's a good or bad thing is for the community to decide, I'm just pointing out the relevant fact.)

Comment: The Community♦ Bot has over 10,000 helpful flags, here on Meta, and over 200,000 on Stack Overflow. Should that (and other, possibly *non*-bot ♦s) be on the leaderboard?

Comment: @AdrianMole Community♦ in this case is a special aggregate of all the users stats belonging to accounts that were deleted or dissociated. (Somewhat surprisingly Community♦ would not have any bot actions in this case.)